# Can't access data in array using input

Tags: laravel, input

The doc tells:
When working on forms with "array" inputs, you may use dot notation to access the arrays:

```
$input = Input::get('products.0.name');
```

ok .. so I have this array:

```
array(3) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "kxIJp6UAzBhi4zwymO4MYO17KtuGQjS5EL6KLDDX" ["product_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["category_id"]=> string(2) "15" }
```

What is the correct syntax to access values for product_id and category_id ?? I can't figure out

Comment: what does your HTML for the form look like?

Comment: try `$input = Input::get('products')['product_id '];` and `$input = Input::get('products')['category_id '];`